# Ansible: Shared connection to xxx closed

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, virtual-machine

Hello guys I make a simple playbook to practice with Ansible but I have a problem when I try to run the playbook (`ansible-playbook -i hosts.ini playbook.yml`) to configure an instance ec2 the output returns:

```
> fatal: [XX.XXX.XXX.XXX]: FAILED! => {
>     "changed": false, 
>     "failed": true, 
>     "invocation": {
>         "module_name": "setup"
>     }, 
>     "module_stderr": "Shared connection to XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX closed.\r\n", 
>     "module_stdout": "/bin/sh: 1: /usr/bin/python: not found\r\n", 
>     "msg": "MODULE FAILURE" }     to retry, use: --limit @/home/douglas/Ansible/ansible_praticing/projeto2.retry
> 
> PLAY RECAP
> *********************************************************************
> XX.XXX.XXX.XXX             : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

When I try to connect with the instance via `ssh -i ~/.ssh/key.pem ubuntu@public.ip` it works well but the provisioning not.

My playbook:

```
- hosts: projeto
  sudo: True
  remote_user: ubuntu
  vars_files:
    - vars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: "Update"
      apt: update_cache=yes

    - name: "Install the Ansible"
      apt: name=ansible state=latest

    - name: "Installt the mysql"
      apt:
      args:
        name: mysql-server
        state: latest

    - name: "Install the Nginx"
      apt:
      args:
        name: nginx
        state: latest
```

My `hosts.ini` is also ok (with public ip of aws ec2 instance) and I put the public key (`~/.ssh/id_rsa.pem` of local machine) in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file, inside of the instance.

In the last week (Friday) this playbook was working well.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's quite clear from the error message, it can't find the `/usr/bin/python` on the target node. All the other information you included is rather irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04 target? There's no Python 2.x by default...

Comment: @techraf's comment is right on spot. A cosmetic comment: You can actually remove the `args:` keyword when using `apt`: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/apt_module.html.

Comment: @techraf I understand but the /usr/bin/python it is in the right local.

Comment: @xeroqu The error has nothing to do with the args, I already tested this

Comment: @DouglasDiasdaSilva I know. That's why it was a 'cosmetic' comment. The problem is that either you don't have Python installed or it's in another location.

Comment: @xeroqu 
That's weird I have all versions of python installed in my machine and have in the right directory also.

Comment: a naive question: your hosts file has the correct ec2 instance, right? so, you're not deploying stuff via ansible to another machine...You can also put `-vvvv` flag to see more output.

Comment: I went to check again, just in case, I'm sure that the ip in the inventory is exactly the same as the instance that I want to provision.

Comment: @xeroqu ok, I gonna edit the issue and put the output -vvv

Comment: one final question: is `ubuntu` a sudo user on the remote machine?

Comment: @xeroqu Yeah,is ubuntu !

Comment: hmm, ok. Replacing  `remote_user` with `sudo_user` probably might be a bit more correct (in general), but I'm not sure whether it will help.

Comment: @xeroqu  did what you recommends, the previous error did not happen but now have another error:fatal: [XX.XXX.X.XX]: FAILED! => { "failed": true, "msg": "failed to transfer file to Please login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\"./setup.py:\n\nPlease login as the user \"ubuntu\" rather than the user \"root\".\n" }

Comment: @xeroqu Dude,  I corrected the trouble: just add  "connection: local" line before "user:ubuntu" and thats works ...sorry for taking your time and thanks for the attention

Answer (score 5):

Maybe my answer is too late but I faced the same problem today. I have an Ubuntu 16.04 instance running on my EC2. I think, since it has Python 3 (Python 3.5) as its default Python installation. Hence, ansible is not able to find the required Python directory (`/usr/bin/python`). I got around this issue by changing the ansible Python interpreter to Python 3.

I added `ansible_python_interpreter=/usr/bin/python3` to my inventory file and did not have to change the playbook.

Reference - http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/python_3_support.html

Comment: Awesome, worked like a charm. Note to anyone reading: the `ansible_python_interpreter` is the path to the executable ON THE SERVER, not on your local. Took me a minute to realize that.